# .NET DiscUtils how to write a file into vhd(virtaul hdd)

Tags: .net

here my code

```
  using (VirtualDisk vhdx = DiscUtils.Vhd.Disk.OpenDisk(vhd_filename, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            FatFileSystem vhdbNtfs = new FatFileSystem(vhdx.Partitions(0).Open());
            string filePathOnDisk = "Win.exe";
            using (FileStream fileOnDisk = new FileStream(filePathOnDisk, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFERLENGTH - 1 + 1];
                using (Stream file_create = vhdbNtfs.OpenFile(vhdbNtfs.Root.FullName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    while ((__InlineAssignHelper(bytesRead, fileOnDisk.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFERLENGTH))) != 0)
                    {
                        file_create.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

getting error on "vhdbNtfs.OpenFile"

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not locate file'

Comment: Is your file stored in the same folder as this program?

Comment: no its not in the same folder

Comment: You need to put full path for filePathOnDisk, so your program can find it

Comment: getting the error message ; System.IO.IOException: 'Attempt to write to read-only stream'

Comment: ok i manage to solve the above problem with opening disk with FileAccess.ReadWrite